# F# Sql Type Provider and .NET Framework v4.0/4.5 on Windows 10

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm trying write an application using F# and I need to access a Sql database.  I am trying to use the Sql type provider but when I do:

```
type schema = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString="...">
```

I get the following design time error:

```
The type provider 'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an error: The .NET SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools could not be found
```

A lot of people seem to get this but the only solution I've seen is to download and install the Windows Software Development Kit for Windows 8.1.  I have done this, selected all the options (including .NET SDK 4.5) and it appears to have installed without error.  However this hasn't fixed the issue and when I look in Programs and Features I can see 4.5.1 SDK and 4.6 SDK installed but not 4.5 SDK.  I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.  Has anyone else had this problem and got a solution?

Alternatively is there any good alternative type provider or solution for connecting to and querying (note I only need to read data, not write) from a sql database in F#?

EDIT: Registry keys were missing so I added [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools] with an InstallationFolder value pointing to the correct directory with all the utilities required in it.  As far as I can tell from: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/Util.fs this is all that is required.  However this didn't have any effect.  I looked back at an older version of Util.fs and it seemed to only look for v8.0A, not v8.1A so I also created a key for that, again pointing at the correct folder but still no luck.  At this stage from looking at the code I believe everything necessary is in place for it to work but it's just not.  I'm not sure if the type provider needs to re-installed but I can't find any options to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be hitting this issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/637 , the fix for which was in the pull request here https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/638 .  Looking at the changes in the pull request, it looks like the current version is looking for the following registry keys:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools
```

On my machine, I have SDK versions v7.0A, v7.1, v7.1A, v8.0A, and v8.1A, and SQL type providers work fine.

Can you check your registry, and try downloading and installing one of the above SDKs if you are indeed missing either of them?

Comment: Yes I dug around in the code and discovered this.  I added the keys and pointed them at the correct place but still failing for same reason

Comment: I've never had to explicitly install the SDKs, I've only ever installed Visual Studio with F# and things have worked, and I'm running VS2015 on Windows 10.  However, the thread on github mentioned above indicates that it's only an issue for a clean Windows 10 install, while I have had previous versions of both VS and Windows on the machine.

Comment: Ironically the reason I my windows install is fresh is because I had all kinds of issues installing vs typescript integration because of previous versions of .net/visual studio.  It feels like every Microsoft SDK and toolkit has (un)installation issues these days.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was enough to install this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk